# d3.map puts data in the same x position

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, graph, position

I have a list of words with the frequency that they are used. In this particular list I have one word that shows up two times in this list. I want this to be displayed in my graph.
I have a plunker for this. The URL is Click [here](http://plnkr.co/bPYyZcoPY0cvO6yX8udS)

```
       var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0,width], .1); 
        //y scaling
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height,0]);
        //set up of xAxis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(xScale)
            .orient("bottom");
        //set up of yAxis
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(yScale)
            .orient("left");

xScale.domain(ranks.map(function(d) {return d.word;}));
console.log(ranks.map(function(d) {return d.word;}));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(ranks, function(d) { return (d.frequency)*1.2; })])

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "xaxis")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {return "translate(0," + height + ")";})
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "yaxis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(ranks)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(d.word); })
    .attr("y", function(d) {return yScale(d.frequency); })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {return height - yScale(d.frequency); })
    .style("fill", "steelblue");
```

example of my word list

```
Rank  word
 1     the
 2     be
 3     of
 4     and
 5     a
 6     in
 7     to
 8     have
 9     it
 10    to
 11    for
```

When the graph is drawn and I inspect the element and find that all 11 bars were made but the x position of the rank 7 and 10 are the same. I don't know how to prevent this. I know it has to do with them being the same word. 
 If you need more information like more code please just ask and I'll add more.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: please create a fiddle or plnkr

Comment: Add code you used for creating xScale. Seems like you will have to calculate x positions using index to allow repeated x values.

Comment: do you mean like addiing and i to the function? 'xScale.domain(ranks.map(function(d,i) {return d.word;}));'